# Radeditor error using image manager in IE9

Tags: c#

I am using RadEditor inside Update Panel.
On using image manager in  i got error in IE9

Microsoft JScript runtime error: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)

whereas image manager  works in IE8

inside update panel i have

< telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" ExternalDialogsPath="~/EditorDialogs" runat="server"
                    Width="500px" Height="250px" EditModes="Design" ToolsFile="~/ToolsFile.xml" >
  < ImageManager ViewPaths="~/myPics" UploadPaths="~/myPics"  />

on code behind i used

Telerik.Web.UI.RadFileExplorer rfe = (Telerik.Web.UI.RadFileExplorer)this.FindRadControl(this.Page);
        if (rfe != null)
        {
            rfe.Upload.EnableFileInputSkinning = false;
        }
 private Control FindRadControl(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {

```
        if (c is Telerik.Web.UI.RadFileExplorer) return c;
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            Control sub = FindRadControl(c);
            if (sub != null) return sub;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please help.